# x-gzip token in accept encoding header

Tags: http, headers, fingerprint

The MDN web docs [Content-Encoding page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) says that the x-gzip token is an alias for gzip in the Content-Encoding http header.

But the [accept-encoding page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) doesn't mention it.

Is there a list of headers by browser versions or system versions that uses x-gzip ?
Where does this alias come from ?

Is using x-gzip in Accept-Encoding legit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's legitimate (well, it *used to be* legitimate) in both usage and specification.

`x-` is a common prefix for nonstandard (or "not yet standard") identifiers, often explicitly allowed by protocols, often a de facto convention by implementers.

So `x-gzip` used to be widespread in HTTP/1.0 and originally meant that the format didn't yet have the name entered into the official [Table Of Content Encodings](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml#content-coding) maintained by IANA (if the table even existed back then). [For example,](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm) Opera 4 or 5 used to send this token.

The `gzip` token was made standard [since HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5), and indeed the HTTP/1.1 specification says that `x-gzip` is an acceptable alias for compatibility purposes – it's certainly not something MDN just made up.

However, the big downside of this convention is that once the name gets standardized, the old `x-` version still sticks around for decades and software have to support both. Often newly written documentation will intentionally omit the old aliases to discourage their use. See also [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648), which discusses the history and even mentions this exact token in [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648#appendix-B).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These rfc links are useful and interesting. Are you sure that it is legit in accept-encoding, not only in content-encoding (does a source mention it ?). I can't find common browsers versions that send it, only crawlers and bots.

Comment: All `x-` tokens are "legit" in the sense that the protocol allows them. And if a given encoding is legit in reply's Content-Encoding, that implies it's legit in the request's Accept-Encoding as well (because the server can't use an encoding that the client didn't ask for!) Common browsers no longer send `x-gzip` – it's a relic of distant past. (see last edit).

Comment: If you want to be specific, see RFC 2616 or RFC 7231 and note that HTTP does not directly define the values of either of those headers – instead it defines a group of "content-coding" tokens, and the syntax definitions of both headers simply reference "content-coding". The primary source of allowed tokens is [the IANA registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml#content-coding), while tables in MDN &c. are secondary sources.

Comment: Correction: I think I was wrong in saying that HTTP explicitly allows `x-...` tokens (although there are many _other_ protocols which do). However, it does allow `x-gzip` specifically.